# mongoDB Aggregation - Match 2 conditions at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to perform an operation that matches 2 conditions:

- id1 -> matches array of Ids
- id2 -> matches array of Ids.

I have Chat model with users (array of Id's).

```
const ChatSchema = new Schema(
  {
    users: {
      type: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }]
    },
    messages: {
      type: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message'
      }]
    },
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

Aggregation Query:

```
return await _chat.aggregate([{
    $match: { // Here I nedd to match both cases
      $expr: { $in: [userId1, "$users"] },
      $expr: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId2), "$users"] }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { totalMessages: { "$size": "$messages" } } },
  {
    $project: {
      users: 1,
      messages: { $slice: ["$messages", -20] },
      totalMessages: 1,
      createdAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: this._message.collection.name,
      localField: 'messages',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'messages',
    }
  }
])
```

I tried using `$and` but it is not working in the `$match` stage.

Does anyone know how can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/),

```
{
  $match: {
    users: {
      $all: [userId1, mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId2)]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect!. Thank you